# Is the CASE expression a black box to the SQL Server query optimizer?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization, case, sql-view

I want to know if the SQL Server query optimizer is ever smart enough to look inside a `CASE` expression when it figures out execution plans.

For purposes of reporting, I have written a `view` that encapsulates logic for classifying records.  It adds a "status" column based on a number of lookups elsewhere in the database.  Here's a simple example:

```
create view LibraryBook_with_Status
as
select
    LibraryBook.*,
    case
        when (some logic) then 'Deleted'
        when (more logic) then 'Checked Out'
        when (more logic) then 'Out for Repair'
        when (more logic) then 'On Hold'
        else 'On the Shelf'
        end as [Status]
from
    LibraryBook 
    left outer join 
    (bunch of other tables used in Status calculation, preserving cardinality)
```

I would like to use this `view` in other queries and have SQL Server create execution plans that takes the `CASE` logic into account.  For example:

```
select * 
from LibraryBook_with_Status 
where [Status] = 'Deleted'
```

If this query was written referencing only base tables instead of the `view`, it would only use `LibraryBook` and those tables in the first clause of the `CASE` expression.  But, based on my rudimentary tests, SQL Server seems to be calculating the status of *all* rows and then filtering. This is much more inefficient.

If the `CASE` expression really is a black box, then I see a trade-off between maintainability and query execution speed.

So, is it not possible to encapsulate logic like this without compromise?  Is there some way of formulating a `view` that enables more efficient query plans to be built?

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, I ended up deciding the performance hit was acceptable. The `case` version is very compact and represents the exact logic I need (it's refactored from a stored procedure). To split it up per the proposed answers, I'd have to duplicate all previous status logic evalutaions in each successive status evaluation. i.e., `[Out for Repair] = not [Deleted] and not [Checked Out] and (new logic for Out for Repair)`.

Answer (score 1):

With something like this, QO should be able to do join pruning based on the columns actually used (in SELECT and WHERE):

```
create view LibraryBook_with_Status
as
select
    LibraryBook.*,
    IIF(DeletedBooks.DeletedDate IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS IsDeleted,
    IIF(BookCheckout.CheckoutDate IS NOT NULL AND BookCheckout.CheckinDate IS NULL, 1, 0) AS IsCheckedOut,
    IIF(BookRepair.RepairStartDate IS NOT NULL AND BookRepair.RepairEndDate IS NULL, 1, 0) AS IsOutForRepair
from
    LibraryBook 
    left outer join DeletedBooks ON ...
    left outer join BookCheckout ON ...
    left outer join BookRepair ON ...
```

and then:

```
select a, b, c  --  columns from LibraryBook
from LibraryBook_with_Status
where IsDeleted = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

why not make the view a 'union all' where each member subset is comprised of the rows with the indicated status, performance might vary depending on the logic for Status calculation and how often the view is used with Status in the where clause.

just a thought.

```
select
    LibraryBook.*,
    [Status] = 'Deleted'
from LibraryBook
left outer join (bunch of other tables used in Status calculation, preserving cardinality)
where (some logic indicating status is 'Deleted')

union all

select
    LibraryBook.*,
    [Status] = 'Checked Out'
from LibraryBook
left outer join (bunch of other tables used in Status calculation, preserving cardinality)
where (some logic indicating status is 'Checked Out')

union all
    :
```